# Oracle SQL Distinct Clause not presenting distinct values

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, distinct, clause

I have a script when I'm trying to select locations in an inventory where quantity of said location is <= 5. The query is complete, now I'm trying to do some fine tuning, and what I'm running into now is when I use the distinct clause I am still receiving duplicate records in the same column. I do know the column next to the first are unique, but I thought distinguishing distinct and one column would roll over to next related to said column.

Here is my code:

```
select DISTINCT bin.scannable_id as bin, 
  bi.bin_id as case1,
  pallet.scannable_id as pallet,       
 -- bi.isbn as fcsku, 
  nvl(fs.asin,bi.isbn) as asin, 
  sum(bi.quantity) as quantity, 
  pallet.creation_date as received_date 
  from containers bin 
  join containers pallet on pallet.containing_container_id = bin.container_id 
  join containers case on case.containing_container_id = pallet.container_id 
  join bin_items bi on bi.container_id = case.container_id 
  left join fcskus fs on fs.fcsku = bi.isbn 
  where bin.scannable_id like 'R-1-T%'
  and bi.quantity <= '5'
  group by bin.scannable_id, pallet.scannable_id, bi.bin_id, bi.owner,bi.isbn,nvl(fs.asin,bi.isbn), pallet.creation_date
  order by sum(bi.quantity);
```

My output, which is obviously showing duplicate records in the scannable_id column:
[image]

**Correct Formatting Thanks to conrad.**

```
    select DISTINCT bin.scannable_id as bin,   
  pallet.scannable_id as pallet,       
   nvl(fs.asin,bi.isbn) as asin, 
  sum(bi.quantity) as quantity   
  from containers bin 
  join containers pallet on pallet.containing_container_id = bin.container_id 
  join containers case on case.containing_container_id = pallet.container_id 
  join bin_items bi on bi.container_id = case.container_id 
  left join fcskus fs on fs.fcsku = bi.isbn 
  where bin.scannable_id like 'R-1-T%'
  having sum(bi.quantity) <= '5'
  group by bin.scannable_id, pallet.scannable_id, nvl(fs.asin,bi.isbn), bi.quantity
  order by sum(bi.quantity);
```

Comment: Are you sure that BIN column isn't longer than what you show us?

Comment: DISTINCT applies to the whole row not just the first field

Comment: Bin column is MUCH MUCH longer, than what is shown.

Comment: You are receveiving duplicate columns most likely because of the date field. You you do not specify the format depending on your sql oracle client it will not show the time that it is on the table.

Comment: DISTINCT is applied for the entire row and not to a particular column (if you already are not aware of it). The values in `CASE1` column are distinct here...

Comment: @ConradFrix how do I distinguish it to the column?

Comment: What's the business rule for deciding which case1 value to display? First one, last one, arbitrary?

Comment: try this: `to_char(pallet.creation_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')` and put the same on group by. Also you don't need a distinct if you have a group by

Comment: on case1 it doesn't matter, the only things that TECHNICALLY matter are bin, pallet, asin, quantity.

Comment: Then drop it from your SELECT and GROUP BY Clauses

Comment: Similar to Jorge, trunc(pallet.creation_date), is my standard approach when I am grouping and one of the columns is a date type.

Comment: Updated my question, with an update

Comment: You probably want to use the Having clause. e.g. `Having  sum(bi.quantity) <= 5` instead of the where clause

Comment: That did the trick Conrad! Thanks! Can I mark a comment as an answer?

Comment: [nope](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1555/148672) but that's cool just mark the answer that helped you most

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said on the comments you dont need a `DISTINCT` if you have the `group by` statement. And format your date field because depending on your oracle client configuration it will not show you the entire date format (e.g. date time). So try with this:

```
select  bin.scannable_id as bin, 
        bi.bin_id as case1,
        pallet.scannable_id as pallet,       
        nvl(fs.asin,bi.isbn) as asin, 
        to_char(pallet.creation_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as received_date 
        sum(bi.quantity) as quantity, 
  from containers bin 
     join containers pallet on pallet.containing_container_id = bin.container_id 
     join containers case on case.containing_container_id = pallet.container_id 
     join bin_items bi on bi.container_id = case.container_id 
     left join fcskus fs on fs.fcsku = bi.isbn 
 where bin.scannable_id like 'R-1-T%'
   and bi.quantity <= '5'
 group by bin.scannable_id, 
          pallet.scannable_id, 
          bi.bin_id, 
          bi.owner,
          bi.isbn,
          nvl(fs.asin,bi.isbn), 
          to_char(pallet.creation_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
 order by sum(bi.quantity);
```

Comment: This answer was most helpful. With a combination from comments. Thanks everyone extremely gifted and helpful!

Answer (score 0):

`bi.bin_id` is different for each row, so you do only have distinct results in your resultset.

- `distinct` is applied to the *final visible* resultset (once the `to_char` etc. functions are processed)
- `distinct` is redundant if you already use a `group by` expression

Solution: skipp the `bi.bin_id` column from your select expression.

Your logic is also confusing. You want to know the SUM of all the bi.* elements. To do so you cannot group by `bi.bin_id` nor any field from the `bi` table. This is the reason why your `quantity` result is always 1.